# Which root lattices have a theta series with this property?

Tags: modular-forms, integer-lattices, arithmetic-functions, root-systems, theta-functions

Suppose $\Lambda$ is a root lattice (the integral lattice generated by a crystallographic root system). Consider its theta series

$$\theta_{\Lambda}(q) = \sum_{a\in \Lambda} q^{(a,a)/2},$$

where $(\cdot,\cdot)$ denotes the Euclidean inner product.

My question is:

> For which $\Lambda$ do we have
>
> $$\theta_{\Lambda}(q) = 1+m\sum_{n>0}\frac{f(n)\: q^n}{1-q^n}$$
>
> where $m$ is a nonzero integer and $f$ is a [totally multiplicative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completely_multiplicative_function) arithmetic function?

Equivalently, $\theta_{\Lambda}(q) = 1+m\sum_{n>0} \sigma_f(n)\: q^n$, where the coefficients $\sigma_f(n) = \sum_{d|n} f(d)$ factorize as $\sigma_f(n) = \prod_{p|n} \frac{f(p)^{1+\nu_p(n)}-1}{f(p)-1}$ for prime $p$.

---

I know that the lattices $A_1, A_1^2, A_2, A_2^2, D_4$ and $E_8$ have that property, with

$$f(n) = \lambda(n),\: \left(\frac{-4}{n}\right),\: \left(\frac{-3}{n}\right),\: n \chi_3(n),\: n \chi_2(n), \: n^3$$

and

$$m = 2,\: 4,\: 6,\: 12,\: 24,\: 240$$

respectively (where $\lambda$ is the Liouville function, $\left(\frac{a}{n}\right)$ is a Kronecker symbol and $\chi_a(n)$ is the principal Dirichlet character modulo $a$). These lattices also appear in [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Norman_Johnson5/publication/279194464_Integers/links/558e03ca08aed6ec4bf36912/Integers.pdf?origin=publication_detail) as the six maximal systems of "hypercomplex integers". For the other four nonmaximal systems ($A_1^4, A_1^8, A_2^4, D_4^2$), $f$ is multiplicative but not totally so.

I also found the lattice $E_8\times E_8$, with $f(n)=n^7$ and $m=480$.

I have looked at some other theta series in the OEIS, including those for indecomposable root lattices in low dimensions, but so far I haven't found any other such lattice satisfying all the requirements. In every case I checked, either some coefficient fails to be divisible by $m$, or $\sigma_f(4)$ is not equal to $(\sigma_f(2)-1)^2+\sigma_f(2)$ as complete multiplicativity demands. It's possible that the seven I found are the only ones, but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: It is quite the topic of [Siegel-Weil's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siegel%E2%80%93Weil_formula)

Comment: @reuns Thank you! I looked up the formula but I'm not sure how to apply it to my question. Any hint or reference would be appreciated.

Comment: A slight generalization of this question has been asked at MathOverflow [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/333086/which-even-lattices-have-a-theta-series-with-this-property).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I self-answered a generalization of this question on MathOverflow, which implies that the seven root lattices above are the only ones with that property.

[Here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/350359) is my answer for anyone interested.